# one button music play/stop with playing in startup of activity android

Tags: android

I have an app with one button for play/stop music . when I run the app , music stops in start up of that . But I want when I run the app that music plays automatically and if I click the button , music stops . I searched the site but I cant find the answer .Please help me my friends.

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test2);

    mainkan=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    mainkan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            go();
         }

        });

     public void go(){
mp=MediaPlayer.create(ProjectisengActivity.this, R.raw.test);
if(mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.seekTo(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this:

```
if (mp == null) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(ProjectisengActivity.this, R.raw.test);
}

if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.pause();
} else {
     mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggle button like below

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call  go() method  in your activity oncreate method.
 Its play automatically on activity start when you button clicked its again call the same method so the condition is palying so its stopped.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.test2);

mainkan=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
go();
mainkan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        go();
     }

    });



public void go(){
mp=MediaPlayer.create(ProjectisengActivity.this, R.raw.test);
if(mp.isPlaying()){
mp.stop();
try {
    mp.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mp.seekTo(0);
```